# PHP - How to turn on safe mode on PHP Version: 5.4.45?

Tags: php

im wondering how to turn on PHP Safe mode on Version: 5.4.45?

im on centos 6 running php-fpm

Answer (score 1):

PHP's safe mode was **removed** in PHP 5.4.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php

Comment: So what is the alternative? if someone manages to upload a shell in my site then they can execute harmful commands?

Comment: @user5675649 Write secure code and keep your third-party libraries updated. Use a framework like Laravel that helps you do that. You can use `disable_functions` in `php.ini` to turn off the various `exec-style` functions - use [the safe mode list](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php) if you like. Fundamentally, safe mode was removed because it didn't actually keep people safe.